# How do I remove the weird space in a tables second cell next to an image?

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I'm new at stack overflow so please excuse if I state the problem a bit unclear, I'll try my best.
I'm trying to basically recreate a picture of a table into an actual html & css table.
The image basically looks like this:

[image]

But this is what I'm getting so far:

[image]

The circled part is the problem, I don't understand why it comes up!

Here is the HTML and CSS I used for this:
(I replaced the actual image links btw, the original height and width of the pics go like this:
pic1: 600x600 px
pic2: 418x347 px
pic3: 2863x2404 px)

```css
.central {
    text-align: center;
}

#pss {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#pss td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 180px;
}

#pss tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    height: 350px;
    
}

#pss td:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#pss th {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #1f3855;
  color: white;
}


#picleft {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table id="pss">
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="2">This is the th part of the table I think</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>Here is: <br>
        &#10003; text <br>
        &#10003; more text<br>
        &#10003; listed<br>
        &#10003; like this<br>
        &#10003; no problem <br>
        
        </td>
    <td>These two: <br>
        &#10003; cells <br>
        &#10003; aka this row<br>
        &#10003; is not the problem </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <div id= "tripod">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x600" alt="tripod">
        </div>
            </td>
    <td>
        <div id= "picright">
            <img src="https://placehold.co/418x347" alt="tripod" width="200"> <br>
            caption of pic 2
        </div>
            <div id= "picleft">
            <img src="https://placehold.co/2863x2404" alt="tripod" width= "280">
                caption of pic 3
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you trying to display anything that could be considered "table data" in the first place here ...? If not, this should rather not use a table to begin with - using them for pure _layouting_ purposes is a mis-use of a table, in the semantic sense.

Comment: The code you have currently shown doesn't appear to reproduce the problem properly, https://jsfiddle.net/su63pm12/ - might be due to the missing images. Please provide a version that matches what your screenshot shows; you can use placeholder images from a service such as https://placehold.co

Comment: Yes, the first row is the main "table data", but either way I need to re-create this image, so I have to do it as a table.

Comment: Oh, I had no idea such placeholder services exist, how nice! I'll edit my post asap

Comment: I agree with CBroe: Your code seems to differ from what you show in the images. Obviously the two have to match for us to be able to explain the white space. My best _guess_ is that the images in the second column are vertically centered, causing them to go down a bit.

Comment: I added placeholder images now, hopefully it's better now!
And how would I fix the vertically centered pictures the best way? I'm sorry if it seems like a silly/simple question, I'm no expert yet haha

Comment: You need to give the table cell holding the two images the CSS: `vertical-align: top;`.

Comment: Yes!! This is exactly what I wanted, thank you so much! Now I gotta figure out how to mark your answer as the right answer haha

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment. This is such a simple issue that it's hardly worth writing a complete answer for it, but somebody might do it. Just make sure it is a good answer, with a proper explanation, if you approve it.